# Flexbox don't work in Fixed div-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to use property "display: flex" in fixed block:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner {
  justify-self: center;
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. I want inner element to be in center of outer horizontally. What is the mistake? Justify-self don't work

Comment: what is the problem? what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Dekel I want inner element to be in center of outer horizontally.

Comment: Add `justify-content: center;` to the `.outer` styles. `align-items` controls vertical alignment (when elements flow in a row).

Comment: @Blazemonger I did a mistake. I want vertically. But it is not important. justify-content don't work too

Comment: @Blazemonger you can run snippet now

Comment: align-items is to be used in parent. use align-self or margin when used in child css rules ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus and why justify-self don't work? run snippet

Comment: justify-self is actually meant to be used with display:grid; for some reason flex did not get it yet ... (i do not have the link to the source if somebody else has got it, please share ;) ) https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#propdef-justify-self https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self#Specifications

Comment: In other words, turn `.outer` into `display:grid` to trigger `justify-self` on `.inner` :)

Comment: Just put `justify-content` on the `.outer` element.

Answer (score 0):

`align-items` is to be used in parent for vertical alignement when displayed in a row, use `justify-content` when displayed in a column.

`align-items` is to be used in parent for horizontal alignement when displayed in a column, use `justify-content` when displayed in a row.

Or `margin` when used in child css rules ;)

as for a reminder : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

align-items in a column

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

justify-content in a row

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

margin in column

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner {
  margin:auto 0;
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

margin in a row

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner {
  margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

margin to center on both axis no matter the flex-direction

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner {
  margin:auto;
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `justify-content` on the `.outer` element. You can also put `align-items` on `.outer` if you want to vertically align as well.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner {
  background-image: url('images/telephone.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```